# image has to be circular without empty spaces in swift

Tags: swift, image

I have a image downloaded from the web and i want to show the image in  circular form.right now the image is not in circular form.It shows white spaces on top and bottom of the imageview.
The code used for the image is as follows:

```
self.profileview.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileview.frame.height / 2
        self.profileview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0       
 self.profileview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.profileimg.clipsToBounds = true
```

The image which appears is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjbV3.png)

How to make the image circular?

Comment: set imageView contentMode so image cover the imageView and display a round shape
`self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` OR `self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , may be it will work in your case .

`myimageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`

or

`myimageviewcontentMode = .scaleToFill`

Comment: it is still trimming the top and bottom and showing like earlier image only

Comment: try .scaleToFill

Comment: thanks it worked.problem was with the function which was downloading the image from url.in that the  content mode was aspectfit and thats why it was trimming the top and bottom space

Comment: welcome d, you can tike right/upvote the answer...:)

Comment: I am unable to upvote it,thats why only tick was possible.